# Firebase Authentication with custom domain

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, firebase-authentication, custom-domain

I have a question about Firebase Authentication for custom domains. I added the dns record and tried to verify the email after 24 hours, but when I click the link I get a 404 error. How can I fix this problem?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have same issue, have you found any solution for this